# How to code latch switch function using STM32?

Tags: stm32, gpio

I am looking a code to get the latch switch function using STM32.
The below code which I have tried is working in stm32 but only a push button function without latch.

```
while (1)
{
      if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_13)== GPIO_PIN_RESET )
      {
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5,GPIO_PIN_SET);
      }
      else
      {
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5,GPIO_PIN_RESET);       
      }         
}
```

Can some one help me to make the GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5 pin high always on the first press of the button and the GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5 low always at the second press ?

The function will be similar as in the below video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzWzSPdxA0U

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: First step if you want help: format the code.

Comment: A couple of things here, please share what the initialization code of the GPIO/s in question.  I cannot effectively give you a good answer if I do not have those.  The logic seems to make sense; however, depending on the switch, you are going to need some debouncing to prevent from accidental toggling of the output.  You should almost never sample a switch like this and make a logical decision based on the first sample.  I am also curious, what is your hardware setup for these pins?  This will determine how to design a digital filter/ debounce code that will give you the behavior you desire.

Comment: Please find the details in this link    https://www.engineersgarage.com/stm32/push-button-and-led-with-stm32f103/

Comment: @JamesNovorita altough everything you said is correct, this code seems more like someone learning how to program/work with electronics so a direct sample and the specific don't matter as much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are several problems with the code. There is no memory function and you are reading the button at max speed.

This is fixed by sleeping for a period of time to allow for human reaction speed and button noise. You also need a variable to store the previous state.

```
while (1)
{
      if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_13)== GPIO_PIN_RESET )
      {
          static bool state = false;
          if(state == false)
          {
              state = true;
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5,GPIO_PIN_SET);
          }
          else
          {
              state = false
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
          }
          while(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_13)== GPIO_PIN_RESET){} // wait for button to be released, otherwise it will keep toggling every 500ms 
      }
      delay_ms(500);
}
```

This is C++ code as it uses `bool`. `int` with the values `1` and `0` can be used for C.

What is done is a variable `state` is declared and kept in heap memory because of the `static` keyword. (Instead of stack memory which would be destroyed when the scope of the outer `if` statement is exited) It is initialized to `false` and then updated when you press the button.

Comment: Your function is same bad as OPs one. To switch you need to wait first for the button release the after the release next press have to toggle the LED. At the moment it only "works" as you have extremely long delay. Keep button pressed and you will see eha it is bad.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland completely correct, will fix now

Answer (score -1):

Possible (crude) solution:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BUTTON_DOWN() (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13) == GPIO_PIN_RESET)
#define LED(on) HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, (on) ? GPIO_PIN_SET : GPIO_PIN_RESET)

static bool _pressed_before = false;
static bool _led = false;

/* somewhere in main loop */
{
    const bool pressed = BUTTON_DOWN();
    if (pressed && !_pressed_before) { /* button pressed? */
        _led = !_led; /* toggle LED state */
        LED(_led);
    }
    _pressed_before = pressed; /* remember state */
}
```

Some notes:
Instead of constantly polling the state, you could use an external GPIO interrupt (search for GPIO EXTI). And it is almost always necessary to use hardware debouncing on the button pin (RC filter) and/or use software debouncing to prevent falsely detected edges. - Also: This question is not really STM32 / hardware specific, so you could find more general answers by searching the webs more broadly on these topics.

Comment: `external GPIO interrupt` worst possible way

Comment: To use an EXTI interrupt to catch a button press event provides best possible input latency and can be straight forward to use. Depending on the application, it can be nice to not poll the state, esp. when the button press should be handled as quickly as possible, and should have direct effect on hardware level (e.g. flip a bit in a register right in the ISR, no external handler necessary). - Could you maybe elaborate a bit why you think it's the "worst possible way"?

Comment: `st possible input latency` yep - that important for something pressed by humans :D

Comment: In certain scenarios, it can certainly have advantage to use interrupts for button events. If the main loop just reads the pin every other second, because it is working on a time critical task, it can be nice to handle button press events right in the ISR, or set a flag that is handled elsewhere in code.

Comment: [(nice tutorial on button interrupts)](https://embedded.fm/blog/2016/11/13/discovery-button-interrupts)

Comment: EXTI are the worst solution for buttons. Childish tutorials are not changing it